# What is the speed difference between Python's set() and set([])?

Tags: python, performance, set

Is there a big difference in speed in these two code fragments?

1.

```
x = set( i for i in data )
```

versus:

2.

```
x = set( [ i for i in data ] )
```

I've seen people recommending `set()` instead of `set([])`; is this just a matter of style?

Comment: If your set is really that simple you could just do `set(data)`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski good point... my actual code is something like `x = set( my_func(i) for i in data )`

Comment: @spandina -- That's a good candidate for `map`/`itertools.imap` -- You could see how those perform compared to a "vanilla" list-comp or generator expression.

Comment: @spandina -- In my simple test, `set(imap(my_func,data))` out performs `map`, list-comp, generator-expression (ordered from fastest to slowest) -- But all the timings are really close ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The form

```
x = set(i for i in data)
```

is shorthand for:

```
x = set((i for i in data))
```

This creates a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) which evaluates lazily.  Compared to:

```
x = set([i for i in data])
```

which creates an entire list *before* passing it to `set`

---

From a performance standpoint, generator expressions allow for short-circuiting in certain functions (`all` and `any` come to mind) and takes less memory as you don't need to store the extra list -- In some cases this can be very significant.

If you actually are going to iterate over the entire iterable `data`, and memory isn't a problem for you, I've found that typically the list-comprehension is slightly faster then the equivalent generator expression*.

```
temp $ python -m timeit 'set(i for i in "xyzzfoobarbaz")'
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.55 usec per loop
temp $ python -m timeit 'set([i for i in "xyzzfoobarbaz"])'
100000 loops, best of 3: 3.42 usec per loop
```

Note that if you're curious about speed -- Your fastest bet will probably be just:

```
x = set(data)
```

proof:

```
temp $ python -m timeit 'set("xyzzfoobarbaz")'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.83 usec per loop
```

*Cpython only -- I don't know how Jython or pypy optimize this stuff.

Comment: About the speed: it's to be expected. When you create a set from a list the set already knows in advance the size and thus can avoid a lot of reallocation which, even though is done to allow O(1) amortized time for inserts, brings big constants for many insertions.
Also iterating at C-level is much faster than at python level so the time taken to iterate on the list is much smaller then the time taken by reallocations.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- But it allowed me to write this fantastic answer which you might not have been privileged to see if you answered first :-)

Answer (score 3):

The `[]` syntax creates a list, which is discarded immediatley after the set is created. So you are increasing the memory footprint of the program.

The generator syntax avoids that.

Comment: Not just the memory footprint, but also the run time because the data is iterated over twice -- first to create the list and second to convert the list to a set.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski -- I've found that list-comprehensions are typically slightly *faster* than generator expressions (in cpython)

Comment: @StevenRumbalski -- In terms of speed, the main thing you gain is the ability to short-circuit which can be *HUGE*